# Trim around windshield is coming loose

Tags: ford, focus, windshield

Car:  2007 Ford Focus, 110,000 miles

The trim around the outside of the windshield started coming loose when I drive at highway speeds.  It doesn't appear to have been attached with adhesive, but perhaps that came off already?

The trim is a hard plastic and partially slips over the edge of the glass.

So, two questions:

1. Should I attempt to use an adhesive to reattach this?
2. If so, what is the appropriate adhesive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the trim is still in usable condition (not dry/cracked/brittle) then using adhesive is perfectly fine. 3m makes an adhesive exactly for this purpose. Part no: 08008 - 3M® Black Super Weatherstrip Adhesive

Comment: The trip is a hard plastic and partially slips over the edge of the glass.  I was also thinking of just a black silicone sealant?

Comment: Mineral oil is another option:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HOrbQmAcKI&t=185s

Answer (score 0):

Bert is correct- that would be the best answer, however its all up to you. The black silicone would work even on dry brittle cracked weatherstrip. -for awhile at least. Use a better adhesive- like Berts recommendation- waterproof if possible.if the weatherstripping is dry brittle cracked or whatever it doesn't have to be changed out. 3M also makes an adhesive/silicone that dries and creates its own barrier as well.